# Count the number of results

Tags: python, list, count

I have a homework where I have to print the number of results (range(1,36), 7) where are no numbers consecutive. I have already wrote the python script for that, but no idea how to count the lines of the results what is something like this:

> (1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 16, 34)
>
> (1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 16, 35)
>
> (1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 17, 18)
>
> ...

What I expecting for result is: **6711905**

And here is my little script:

```
from itertools import combinations
 
def count_consecutive(l): 
    counts = [1]
    counts_index = 0
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        if l[i] == l[i-1] + 1:
            counts[counts_index] = counts[counts_index] + 1
        else:
            counts.append(1)
            counts_index += 1
    return max(counts)     

for comb in combinations(range(1,36), 7):
    if count_consecutive(comb) not in [5, 6, 7]:
        #print (comb)
```

Comment: If you need to count the permutations `where are no numbers consecutive`, what's `if count_consecutive(comb) not in [5, 6, 7]` for? Shouldn't it be `if count_consecutive(comb) == 0`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
counting=0
for comb in combinations(range(1,36), 7):
    if count_consecutive(comb) not in [5, 6, 7]:
        print (comb)
        counting+=1
print (counting)
```

This will give you the number that you want, after each *print* adding 1 to *counting* variable. when *for* loop is end, it will print the last value of *counting* variable.

> Example:

```
counting=0
for comb in combinations(range(1,10),3):
    print (comb)
    counting+=1
print ("The number of counts is:",counting)
```

Output:

```
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 2, 5)
(1, 2, 6)
(1, 2, 7)
(1, 2, 8)
(1, 2, 9)
(1, 3, 4)
(1, 3, 5)
(1, 3, 6)
....
....
....
(6, 8, 9)
(7, 8, 9)
The number of counts is: 84
```

> **Edit:** Here is more pythonic:

```
list1=[comb for comb in combinations(range(1,10),3)]
print (len(list1))
```

Output:

```
>>> 
84
>>>
```